# What is the function of the open port 7654 on Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, security, port, azure-web-app-service

We had a security scan of our application hosted on Azure Web Apps. They found some open ports that are listed in the image below:

[image: openports]

We can explain almost all open ports, except 7654. Does anyone know what this port is used for? Or is there any gihub repo or other place we can ask MS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot close these ports as Azure Web Apps are multi tenant environment by design.

Description of these ports is available  on [How To Control Inbound Traffic to an App Service Environment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic/).

> 7654: (including this one to document all possible ports which can be seen with App Service): Metadata endpoint used by the internal service (does not take any input, only returns an IP address).

For more details, you could refer to this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9bcfc43-b962-47ef-a856-36bf5f9e9bdd/open-ports-for-web-apps?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed the MSDN answer in my search.

Comment: Jep, I can use this for explaining it to the security guys.